# Binary Expression Tree

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, math-expression-eval

I implemented a binary expression tree, I've used [my previous shunting-yard parser](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/201232/shunting-yard-algorithm) to provide it the post-fix expression.

I have a few specific questions outside of just comments about making it more pythonic:

- Should I check the type when assigning `left` and `right` nodes? I read that type checking is usually discouraged (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6725913/1693004), but the `Node` class is inside the binary_expression_tree module.
- Should the `BinaryExpressionTree` constructor take in the post-fix token expression from the shunting yard parser, or should it take in an infix expression and convert it internally?

Code:

```
import shunting_yard_parser


class Node:
    _left = None
    _right = None
    _token = None

    def __init__(self, token):
        self._token = token

    @property
    def left(self):
        return self._left

    @left.setter
    def left(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, Node):
            raise TypeError("Left node must be of type Node")
        self._left = value

    @property
    def right(self):
        return self._right

    @right.setter
    def right(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, Node):
            raise TypeError("Right node must be of type Node")
        self._right = value

    @property
    def token(self):
        return self._token


class BinaryExpressionTree:

    _root = None

    def __init__(self, postfix_tokens):
        stack = list()

        for token in postfix_tokens:
            if token.kind == shunting_yard_parser.TokenSpecification.OPERAND:
                stack.append(Node(token))
            if token.kind == shunting_yard_parser.TokenSpecification.OPERATOR:
                operator_node = Node(token)

                if len(stack) < 2:
                    raise TypeError('Incorrectly formatted expression - check operators.')

                operator_node.right = stack.pop()
                operator_node.left = stack.pop()

                stack.append(operator_node)

        if len(stack) > 1:
            raise TypeError('Incorrectly formatted expression - check operands.')

        self._root = stack.pop()

    def solve(self):
        assert self._root is not None
        return self._solve(self._root)

    @staticmethod
    def _solve(node):
        if node.token.kind == shunting_yard_parser.TokenSpecification.OPERAND:
            return int(node.token.value)

        left_value = BinaryExpressionTree._solve(node.left)
        right_value = BinaryExpressionTree._solve(node.right)

        operator = node.token.value
        if operator == '+':
            return left_value + right_value
        if operator == '-':
            return left_value - right_value
        if operator == '*':
            return left_value * right_value
        if operator == '/':
            return left_value / right_value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        infix_expression = input('Enter infix expression:')

        postfix_expression = ""
        try:
            postfix_expression = shunting_yard_parser.parse(infix_expression)
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)

        if postfix_expression != "":
            binaryExpressionTree = BinaryExpressionTree(postfix_expression)
            solution = binaryExpressionTree.solve()

            print(solution)
```

Unit tests:

```
from unittest import TestCase
import binary_expression_tree
import shunting_yard_parser


class TestBinaryExpressionTree(TestCase):
    def test_only_operands(self):
        # arrange
        postfix_expression = [shunting_yard_parser.Token(shunting_yard_parser.TokenSpecification.OPERAND, '2'),
                              shunting_yard_parser.Token(shunting_yard_parser.TokenSpecification.OPERAND, '5')]

        # act & assert
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, lambda: binary_expression_tree.BinaryExpressionTree(postfix_expression))

    def test_only_operators(self):
        # arrange
        postfix_expression = [shunting_yard_parser.Token(shunting_yard_parser.TokenSpecification.OPERATOR, '+'),
                              shunting_yard_parser.Token(shunting_yard_parser.TokenSpecification.OPERATOR, '*')]

        # act & assert
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, lambda: binary_expression_tree.BinaryExpressionTree(postfix_expression))

    def test_unbalanced_expression(self):
        # arrange
        postfix_expression = [shunting_yard_parser.Token(shunting_yard_parser.TokenSpecification.OPERAND, '2'),
                              shunting_yard_parser.Token(shunting_yard_parser.TokenSpecification.OPERATOR, '+'),
                              shunting_yard_parser.Token(shunting_yard_parser.TokenSpecification.OPERATOR, '*')]

        # act & assert
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, lambda: binary_expression_tree.BinaryExpressionTree(postfix_expression))

    def test_balanced_expression(self):
        # arrange
        postfix_expression = [shunting_yard_parser.Token(shunting_yard_parser.TokenSpecification.OPERAND, '2'),
                              shunting_yard_parser.Token(shunting_yard_parser.TokenSpecification.OPERAND, '5'),
                              shunting_yard_parser.Token(shunting_yard_parser.TokenSpecification.OPERATOR, '+'),
                              shunting_yard_parser.Token(shunting_yard_parser.TokenSpecification.OPERAND, '10'),
                              shunting_yard_parser.Token(shunting_yard_parser.TokenSpecification.OPERATOR, '*')]

        # act
        tree = binary_expression_tree.BinaryExpressionTree(postfix_expression)

        # assert
        result = tree.solve()
        self.assertEqual(70, result)
```

Shunting-yard algorithm (only for reference, already reviewed):

```
from collections import namedtuple, deque
from enum import Enum
import re


class TokenSpecification(Enum):
    PARENTHESES = 1
    OPERAND = 2
    OPERATOR = 3
    IGNORE = 4
    JUNK = 5


class Token(namedtuple("Token", "kind value")):
    _operatorPrecedence = {"*": 3,
                           "/": 3,
                           "+": 2,
                           "-": 2}

    @property
    def precedence(self):
        if self.kind == TokenSpecification.OPERATOR:
            return self._operatorPrecedence[self.value]
        else:
            raise TypeError("")


def _tokenize(expression):
    token_specification = [
        (TokenSpecification.PARENTHESES.name, r'[()]'),
        (TokenSpecification.OPERAND.name, r'\d+'),
        (TokenSpecification.OPERATOR.name, r'[+\-*/]'),
        (TokenSpecification.IGNORE.name, r'\s+'),
        (TokenSpecification.JUNK.name, r'\S+?\b')
    ]

    tokenizer_regex = '|'.join('(?P<{kind}>{pattern})'.format(kind=kind, pattern=pattern)
                               for kind, pattern in token_specification)

    tokenizer = re.compile(tokenizer_regex)

    for match in tokenizer.finditer(expression):
        kind = match.lastgroup
        value = match.group(kind)

        if kind == TokenSpecification.JUNK:
            raise ValueError('Unrecognized token: {0}'.format(value))
        elif kind != TokenSpecification.IGNORE:
            yield Token(TokenSpecification[kind], value)


def parse(infix_expression):
    operators = deque()

    for token in _tokenize(infix_expression):
        if token.kind == TokenSpecification.OPERAND:
            yield token

        elif token.kind == TokenSpecification.OPERATOR:
            while (operators
                   and operators[0].value != '('
                   and operators[0].precedence >= token.precedence):
                yield operators.popleft()

            operators.appendleft(token)

        elif token.value == '(':
            operators.appendleft(token)

        elif token.value == ')':
            # Pop all the operators in front of the "(".
            while operators and operators[0].value != '(':
                yield operators.popleft()

            # The previous operation would have removed all the operators
            # because there is no matching opening parenthesises.
            if not operators:
                raise ValueError('Unmatched )')

            # Remove matching parenthesis.
            operators.popleft()

    for operator in operators:
        # If there are still opening parenthesises in the stack this means
        # we haven't found a matching closing one.
        if operator.value == '(':
            raise ValueError('Unmatched (')

        yield operator


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        action = input('Enter infix expression:')

        try:
            postfix_expression = parse(action)
            print([op.value for op in postfix_expression])

        except ValueError as e:
            print(e.args)
```